# Where can I get replacement cables of this kind?

Tags: part-identification, electronics, replacement-parts

What I'm looking for:
[image]

This is a 4.5 V cable which is part of an *old* set I once had. I don't have any parts number, but I know this comes in different lengths.

Google told me about bricklink.com and I've searched there but didn't find it.

Comment: Note that it's possible to undo the screws holding the wires into the plugs and replace the electrical wire part with whatever you like - longer, shorter, pretty colours, whatever you like. The main thing is making sure you don't lose the screws.

Comment: Thank you @M(something?). I'm handy with a screwdriver so fixing ones myself are no problem - if I had enough parts. I'm looking at a bag of LEGO from my own childhood and most cables are incomplete... (yes, even missing the pins and the screws) so I need complete replacements. Maybe 11yo me wasn't good at taking care of small things. Maybe that's why I never had a hamster? :-)

Comment: darn, I hoped the photo was of your cable. I had the same problem, but took the motor into an electronic supply place so I could try all the likely looking plugs and eventually found some. They were much cheaper than official Lego ones :)

Comment: That photo is my cable. But it's the only complete one I have, and not in best condition either :-/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an [Electric, Wire 12V / 4.5V](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=x466c28&in=P%7D).

They can be found here:

[Catalog: Parts - Electric, Wire & Connector](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catID=735)

Just find the right length.

Comment: link is now updated